# How to photograph sun bursts through tree canopy?

Tags: post-processing, light, outdoor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get photos showing the “shaft of light” effect?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/how-can-i-get-photos-showing-the-shaft-of-light-effect)

I really like [Lars van de Goor](http://larsvandegoor.com/home_en.html) photography, especially his shots of sun bursts through trees.   I am not sure whether the "dutch light" is a myth and whether it has anything to do with the lighting in his photographs. **I would like to know what sort of weather conditions are needed to produce a photo with strong sun rays bursting trough tree canopy.**   [Here is an example.](http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=352830784793298&set=a.173099492766429.43045.149963245080054&type=1&theater)

I am in Northern Ontario, Canada and the light here is really harsh/sharp and we have very little environmental haze and I don't think I have ever seen anything like this around here. (Maybe I just don't know how to look for the right conditions) I would think hazy/ misty sunny conditions should be good, possibly early in the morning or after rain but but in some Lars van de Goor's images it looks as if the sun rays are too strong, almost unnaturally strong in comparison to the rest of the scene. 
Are weather conditions, timing, hour of day, etc. all that's needed to take such a photograph or are there any other post processing tricks used?

Comment: Relevant: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/how-can-i-get-photos-showing-the-shaft-of-light-effect